# Powershell & Regex - How to find and delete uppercase characters from file names in directory

Tags: regex, powershell, uppercase

I need a Powershell script that will find and replace uppercase characters within **all the filenames within a directory** with nothing.

The script would do something like this:

Filename BEFORE: CAPITAL-letters.jpg

Filename AFTER: -letters.jpg

Edit: I tried running this script, but it didn't work

```
dir | rename-item -NewName {$_.name -replace [Regex]::Escape("[A-Z"),""}
```

Comment: Can you post what you've tried? Please note that this isn't a script request forum.

Comment: `gci c:\directory\ | mv -dest { $_.Name -replace '(?-i)[A-Z]' } -WhatIf`

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler `-creplace "[A-Z]"` works too.

Comment: Darnit, @ConnorLSW, I was only just tripping over regex case sensitivity in another comment, just guessed about `(?-i)` to turn off insensitivity and was feeling pleased that it works, and I forgot the `-cthing` and `-ithing` variants; yes that's nicer.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler yeah it's strange to use case insensitive Regex, confused me for a while too.

Comment: `-creplace '\p{Lu}'` please :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since this got answers, for full clarity:

Remove `-WhatIf` when you're running it.

```
Get-ChildItem | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -creplace "[A-Z]"} -WhatIf
```

This pipes `Get-ChildItem` into `Rename-Item` and then Sets the `NewName` to be the old name, except we've case-sensitively replaced any capital letters with nothing.

Comment: What if I want to run this script with an entire directory?

Comment: @abednabir i'm sure you've figure dit out already - but running this will perform the action on the entire current folder, you can add `-Recurse` to the `Get-ChildItem` command to have it include subfolders.

Comment: My apologies - I was in a bit of a hurry when I left that comment. The script does work for file directories.

Answer (score 2):

```
$test = "CAPITAL-letters.jpg"
$test -creplace "[A-Z]"
```

=> `-letters.jpg`

Comment: whats t e h deal with "-creplace"? :D

Comment: It means it's case sensitive so in this case we replace ONLY capital letters